# how to manipulate data models in django and render on frontend?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-models

I want to manipulate this data on `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Binary(models.Model):

  binNum = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    @property
    def binDec(self): 
       bin = self.binNum
       decimal, i, n = 0, 0, 0
       while(bin != 0): 
          dec = bin % 10
          decimal = decimal + dec * pow(2, i) 
          bin = bin//10
          i += 1
       return decimal
```

I'm doing this and its rendering just the `binNum`:

```
return (
  <ul>

    {this.state.data.map(contact => {
      return (
        <li key={contact.id}>
          {contact.binNum}
          {contact.binNum.binDec} 

        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
)
```

I want to render the `binDec` on the frontend.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `contact.binDec` not `contact.binNum.binDec`?

Comment: i think its better in templatetags